# How do I convert image file to base64?

Tags: reactjs

I am want to save image as base64 to aws s3 bucket. There is a lambda that will decoder the base64.

These are my current states for the images. One is for selected file that is the image and the one is for the image that is seen as preview on the page.

```js
 const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('')
 const [preview, setPreview] = useState()
```

Then I have useEffect function for selecting the file and also sets the object URL as the preview image.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedFile) {
      setPreview(undefined)
      return
    }

    const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)
    setPreview(objectURL)

    return () => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)
  }, [selectedFile])

  const selectFile = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])
  }
```

And this is the input component where the onChange function is called.

```js
 <Input
   style={input}
   type='file'
   accept='.jpg, .png|image/*'
   id='image'
   name='Upload image'
   onChange={selectFile}
 />
```

Is there a better way to handle the base64 conversion?

Comment: You're asking two questions: one about image selection and one about base64 conversion. While your question title is about base64, I'm only seeing code related to file selection and preview. Asking multiple questions in one is discouraged (it's even one of the options behind the "needs improvement" flag) so maybe open two separate questions if you need help with both problems

Comment: I updated the question to be only one @EmmaKoskinen

Comment: Great! I still can’t see any code related to base64 here though. Are you perhaps confusing [blob urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with base64 [data urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue and posted my answer with the solution. It was relatively short lines of code needed. But now I need to figure out how to get image type like png or jpg. Probably need to slice the image name somehow but not sure how to yet

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to mark your answer as accepted, so that this question shows up as closed. Sounds like you could/should open a new question wrt. the file types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this by relatively short lines of code. I take the selectedFile from the state and then convert it to base64. I tested it with the separate button and I got base64 image in the console.

```js
  const convertToBase64 = () => {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile)

    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log('called: ', reader)
      setBase64IMG(reader.result)
    }
  }
```